# HXmap_get not returning the right data with the key

Tags: c, linux, dictionary, data-structures

```
int main()
{
       struct HXmap *limitMap;
        limitMap = HXmap_init(HXMAPT_DEFAULT,HXMAP_CKEY);
        int a[]={1,2,3};
        HXmap_add(limitMap,a,limitMap);
        HXmap_add(limitMap,(a+1),BuyTree);
        HXmap_add(limitMap,&a[2],main);
          int price =1;
          Limit* add = (Limit*)HXmap_get(limitMap,&price);
   printf("Price: %d, Address %p LimitMap %p \n",price,add,limitMap);
        return 0;
}
```

The output of this piece of code is here:

`Price: 1, Address (nil) LimitMap 0x8ff5008`

Why isnt HXmap_get() returning the right address?

Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have [libHX](http://libhx.sourceforge.net/) installed, so this is just guessing based off of the documentation…

Because you did not specify that the keys are C strings, nor provided a key size, nor gave a custom `HXmap_ops`, it's using a direct value comparison instead of following the pointer to `int`.

You can either use `price` directly as the key (without using pointer-to-`int`), or specify the key size.

```
HXmap_init5(HXMAPT_DEFAULT, HXMAP_CKEY, NULL, sizeof(int), 0);
```

Comment: Now I am cursing myself. Damn! I went through the doc 4 times to check the validity of HXmap_init() function but didnt strike me strange not to use it.Thanks it worked.